# oracle escape sequence for dot charecter

Tags: oracle, escaping

I'm trying to insert below value with in quotes into a table. it's give me error. How can i avoid the error.

```
'CASE WHEN index_col IS NULL THEN '.' ELSE index_col END'
```

What is the escape sequence for dot character?  I have tried different options like back slash `\` and `[]` but nothing works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *classical* way is to double the apostrophes:

```
select 
  'CASE WHEN index_col IS NULL THEN ''.'' ELSE index_col END'
from dual;
```

Alternative way is to use the [quoted string](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm)

```
select 
  q'!CASE WHEN index_col IS NULL THEN '.' ELSE index_col END!'
from dual;
```

Anyway the problem is not with the dot character, but with the **apostrophes**.